# c# ef - Best approach to create one-to-zero/one mapping between one common table to other three or more tables

Tags: c#, entity-framework, database-design

I am trying to create a common database table of `Contact` for multiple types, like, `Person`, `Company`, `Branch`, etc using entity-framework 6.1 code first. I am stuck on trying to figure out the best way to implement the one-to-one mapping between a `Contact` and `Person`, `Company`, `Branch` where each of these table entries will have only one `Contact`.

I have four tables for this.

```
public class Contact
{
    public Contact()
    {
        People = new HashSet<Person>();
        Companies = new HashSet<Company>();
        Branches = new HashSet<Branch>();
    }
    public int ContactId { get; set; }

    public ICollection<Person> People { get; set; }
    public ICollection<Company> Companies { get; set; }
    public ICollection<Branch> Branches { get; set; }
}

public class Person
{
    public int PersonId { get; set; }

    public int ContactId { get; set; }
    public virtual Contact Contacts { get; set; }        
}

public class Company
{
    public Company()
    {
        Members = new HashSet<Member>();
    }
    public int CompanyId { get; set; }

    public int ContactId { get; set; }
    public virtual Contact Contacts { get; set; }     
}

public class Branch
{
    public int BranchId { get; set; }

    public int ContactId { get; set; }
    public virtual Contact Contacts { get; set; }
}
```

Problem: In the current implementation I could able to store the multiple contacts for each `Person`, `Company` and `Branch` i.e. Many-to-Many relationship between these table to `Contact`. Instead I would like to store the only one `Contact` for each `Person`, `Company` and `Branch` as naturally it should have only one.

I tried the below Implementation but it gives me error while retrieving the `Contact` information by `PersonId`

```
public class Contact
{
    public Contact()
    {
        People = new HashSet<Person>();
    }
    public int ContactId { get; set; }

    public virtual Person People { get; set; }
}

public class Person
{
    public int PersonId { get; set; }

    public virtual Contact Contacts { get; set; }        
}


public class ContactMap : EntityTypeConfiguration<Contact>
{
    public ContactMap()
    {
        // 1-1 relationships 
        HasOptional(p => p.People).WithOptionalPrincipal(c => c.Contacts).Map(c => c.MapKey("ContactId"));            
    }
}
```

Error while retrieving the `Contact` Info

```
_db.People.Join(_db.Contacts, p => p.ContactId, c => c.ContactId, (p, c) => new { p, c })
          .Select(x => => new
            {
                x.p.PersonId, x.c.ContactId
            })
            .OrderBy(pid => pid.Id)
            .ToList();
```

at `p.ContactId` it throws an error "Cannot resolve the symbol 'ContactId'" since there is no definition of `ContactId` in `Person` entity/class.

Any suggestions would be highly appreciated.

I would like to have an final output/database structure as below:

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have also experienced same problem. In my opinion the best approach here is to create one main table, say `Party`. Create *one-to-one* relationship between this table and your other main tables (`Person`, `Company`, `Branch`) and create *one-to-zero or one* relationship between main table (`Party`) and `Contact` table.

```
/// <summary>
/// Model for Party, which is general form of Persons and Companies
/// </summary>
public class Party
{
    public int PartyID { get; set; }

    // Navigation properties
    public virtual Company Company { get; set; }
    public virtual Person Person { get; set; }
    public virtual Contact Contact { get; set; }
}

public class Person
{
    public int PersonID { get; set; }
    // Other properties.....

    // Navigation properties
    public virtual Party Party { get; set; }
}

public class Company
{
    public int CompanyID { get; set; }
    // Other properties

    // Navigation properties
    public virtual Party Party { get; set; }
}

public class Contact
{
    public int ContactID { get; set; }
    // Other properties...

    // Navigation properties
    public virtual Party Party { get; set; }
}
```

[This link](http://www.universaldatamodels.com/Portals/9/udm_Publication_Articles_11_05_Models_Patterns.pdf) helped me to create my models.